# Star ratings wrong on Google using Schema

Tags: google-schemas

I'm trying to impliment the "Review ratings" schema on my Google listings.

My "total score" structure is as follows:

```
<div class="span7" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <div class="stars" onclick="document.location.href='http://www.chambresdhotes.org/cgi-bin/links/review.cgi?ID=65995'" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
        <span class="badge badge-success">5 avis</span>
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="10" />
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="8" />
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="9.2" />
        <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="5" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, for each of the reviews on that page - I also have:

```
<div class="reviewBox" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <meta itemprop="author" content="Patrice" />
    <meta itemprop="itemreviewed" content="Les Collinades" />
    <div class="reviewRating" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
        <span class="link-rating"><span class="rating-5"></span></span>
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This all shows up OK when doing a schema check on the Google tool here:

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chambresdhotes.org%2FDetailed%2F65995.html

The "overall" ranking / number of reviews etc:

[image]

...and then the individual review scores:

[image]

However, when you go here its wrong:

https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:www.chambresdhotes.org+Detailed%2F65995.html

[image]

I'm a bit baffled as to why its doing this. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've filled out `bestRating` and `worstRating` with the best and worst ratings your business has received. However, these are intended to be used to define the best possible and worst possible ratings.

Going from your example, I assume your customers can rate your business on a scale of 1 to 10. As such, `bestRating` would have to be `10` and `worstRating` would have to be `1`.

You then have to calculate the average overall rating yourself, and put that under `ratingValue`

Comment: Afterthought: The reason why you need to define a bestRating and a worstRating is due to the fact that some businesses might prefer to use a rating out of 5, whereas others would rate out of 10, or even out of 100. Google doesn't know who uses what rating system, and therefore it must be told.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have thought of that! I just assumed that `bestRating` was for the top rating someone had given it - whereas `worstRating`, was the  lowest score someone had given it. I've updated our site now, and I guess we will see how it update. I'm sure it'll fix it, so I've gone ahead and marked this as the correct solution :)

Comment: You're welcome :) To speed the process of Google indexing, you can ask Google to [index your page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en). This should have your updated ratings showing within a day or two. (At least that's how long it took for me)

Comment: just to confirm, this has now taken effect. Thanks!